# Using facebook logo on ios app

Tags: ios, facebook

I develop tightly integrated with the facebook app for ios. And there was a question at the expense of the intellectual property facebook. Can I use in my application this logo.

[image: facebook loge]

This logo will used as a button.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can as long as you follow [facebook Do's and Don'ts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/branding).

Do:

- Design your own logo that represents your brand.

Don't:

- Use or incorporate Facebook's F logo, or any modification or derivative of the F logo, in your icons or logos
- Include the terms Facebook or FB in icons or logos
- Use the FACEBOOK logo
- Use Facebook's other graphics or icons, such as our well-known silhouette logo

Comment: link is broken!

Comment: Updated link in answer

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to "fair use". Seeing as how you're using their logo to link to their open service, under the fair use, you're good to go. :)
However, using their logo for your own social network, which might be named feedbook, or whatnot, WILL get you sued.