# How do you get the Twitter and Facebook icons in your apps

Tags: ios, facebook, image, button, twitter

I created a Twitter and Facebook SHARE buttons. However, I don't know if i'm allowed to use the official Twitter bird logo and the official Facebook F logo as a custom image button on my app. Are developers allowed to do that or are we supposed to get permission from Facebook and Twitter? Or should I just create a custom button that says Facebook, Twitter on it? I've seen only official facebook and twitter logos on game apps and other apps. How is it done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using facebook logo on ios app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681427/using-facebook-logo-on-ios-app)

Comment: https://www.facebookbrand.com/

Answer (score 1):

Both Facebook and Twitter have strict guidelines for that, which you can find on their corresponding developer sites. You will also find the necessary resources (i.e. images) on these sites. It is typically not ok to use custom images.

That said, the official guides are not always followed and personally I have never heard of anyone being held responsible for doing it wrong. But I would strongly encourage you to follow them in any case.

Answer (score 1):

At least for Facebook, I would always advise to use the official SDK and the Share Button it provided. You can read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#triggering

```
FBSDKShareButton *button = [[FBSDKShareButton alloc] init];
button.shareContent = content;  
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Do I also have to include the SHARE DIALOG code along with the Share button code? Or just the Share button code will do?

If I don't use Facebook's SDK i'd get in trouble? Even though I did successfully already implement it without their official SDK.

Comment: The FBSDKShareButton class is part of the iOS SDK. It's not so much that you will get in trouble if you don't want to include the full SDK, but you need it to get that class :) You can check out the prerequisites here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#prereqs. The effect of the Share Button is that it shows the Share Dialog. Please try out the code as described in the documentation and see what the effect is.