# Can I use facebook logo in the activity of my android app

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity

I am developing an android app where I need to put the Facebook app logo and Facebook messenger logo as a very small image for the better understanding for my app users. Neither these logos are attached to any facebook link nor my app. So I am confused if am I allowed to use facebook logo inside my app's activity or am i breaking any law?

I had gone through the [facebookbrand.com](https://en.facebookbrand.com/) but it wasn't helpful for me.

I found the facebookband website from this link [[Using facebook logo on ios app]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681427/using-facebook-logo-on-ios-app) only but as i said above it wasn't helpful for me.

Bear with me if I am doing something wrong when questioning as I am new here.
Thank you.

Comment: i doubt , have a look at this post -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681427/using-facebook-logo-on-ios-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using facebook logo on ios app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681427/using-facebook-logo-on-ios-app)

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Thanks for replying. I had check the facebookbrand.com from that link only. But as i already said. it didn't helped me.

Comment: try material design icons. click **here** (https://materialdesignicons.com/)

Comment: @AkshayDighade Thanks for replying. This looks promising to me. But i still have few doubts. I found the facebook logo there and there is the option to edit the color of the logo too, so after editing am i allowed to use the logo in my app or should i have to include any license file in my app?

Comment: @Shadab Ahmad, its free icon for developers. There is no license or purchase issue.\

Comment: @AkshayDighade Ok and thanks again for the link.